# How do I read xml file with a servlet?

Tags: java, xml, servlets, xml-parsing

I am new to servlet programming.  I need to read a xml file from a client using one.  How can I do this?

Can anyone refer me to some example code? I'm able to parse xml using jaxb, but how can I get the xml itself from the client?

Answer (score 3):

[**HERE**](http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/JSP-Servlet/20574-read-XML-file-and-display-it-using-java-servlets.html) you can find an example code, See below also.

```
import java.io.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class ReadXML extends HttpServlet{ 

    public boolean isTextNode(Node n){
        return n.getNodeName().equals("#text");
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        try{
            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory =  DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse("C:/roseindia.xml");
            out.println("<table border=2><tr><th>Name</th><th>Address</th></tr>");
            Element  element = doc.getDocumentElement(); 
            NodeList personNodes = element.getChildNodes(); 

            for (int i=0; i<personNodes.getLength(); i++){

                 Node emp = personNodes.item(i);
                 if (isTextNode(emp))
                 continue;

                 NodeList NameDOBCity = emp.getChildNodes(); 
                 out.println("<tr>");

                 for (int j=0; j<NameDOBCity.getLength(); j++ ){

                     Node node = NameDOBCity.item(j);
                     if ( isTextNode(node)) 
                     continue;
                    out.println("<td>"+(node.getFirstChild().getNodeValue())+"</td>");

                 } 

                 out.println("</tr>");
             }

             out.println("</table>");

        }

        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

learn to use search engines like google they have lots of handy tutorials on most of the basic and not so basic stuff

exmpale:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-file-uploading.htm

Comment: agreed, some questions are supposed to be  a bit documented before asking